# SSIS Source File validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Using SSIS Package, i am Importing data to SQL from a CSV file.  I need to validate whether file is present, data is present ( size of the file ) and number of columns / datatype is matching with Destination table.

I wrote on script task for file validation and checking the sizing of the file. But i wonder any best option to validate the file and file has any data in it.

Third question is about column mismatch or datatype mismatch Error validation ?

**For finding the column count, i use this syntax**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Database.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Database.dbo.Table')
```

Comment: What do you intend on doing for column mismatch or column number mismatch? This seems like a lot of unnecessary validation work. Instead you could just have the dataflow task fail and have an error flow that would move the file to a different folder say ErrorArchive.

Comment: Package is working fine. But my manager insisted me to handle all the possible validations on the SSIS Package. Though i mentioned about Columns will be automatically ignored if they are not matched.

Comment: you would still recieve a metadata error if you have more columns than you expect in the CSV..

Comment: How many columns are you looking at? One way is to load the CSV file into a staging/temp table and do all your validations before you load it to the target table.

Comment: @TMNT2014, I didnt know that i will face Metadata Error. I was hoping that unmapped columns will be ignored by default. Anyways, i am loading CSV file to a staging Table and check for column / datatype validation and then pushing it to destination table.